# Zip streaming not working in production environment (RAILS/AWS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, zip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, download

I'm having an issue with my rails app exporting large sets of data.

I have several types of data that are related and want to send them together in a zip file (large CSV file, pngs, and other images).

I was creating zip files and sending them to clients until our data set got larger and I was experiencing server overloads and timeouts due to the amount of data.

I switched the code over to use zip_tricks (https://github.com/WeTransfer/zip_tricks) to stream the data.  That along with processing the data in batches seems to have done the trick.  However, the streaming doesn't work in production.

I'm using AWS Elastic Beanstalk for my production server.

Everything works fine on my development server.  The file shows up in the browser as it's being created.  On production everything looks good in the logs, the code works fine.  Just the file doesn't stream.  It just sends an empty zip file.

I thought it might be an NGINX issue but I checked the NGINX logs and there's nothing there.

Here is the controller code that sends the zip stream:

```
   def data_export
   ...
   params stuff
   ...
   zip_tricks_stream do |zip|



  ####  CSV #########
  zip.write_deflated_file('report1.csv') do |sink|
    CSV(sink) do |csv|
      # csv << Person.column_names
       lookup = { taken: "Date of Course", id: "Student ID", workname: 'Student Name', name: 'Employer Name', title: "Course Name", provider: "Course Provider", instructor: "Instructor", expiry: "Expiry Date" }
       csv << lookup.values
       # CSV::Row.new(lookup.values, true)
      @workers.find_each(batch_size: 20) do |work| 
        # csv << person.attributes.values
        ...
        CSV code
        ...
            csv << lookup.keys.map { |attr| combo["#{attr}"] }
          end
      end
    end
  end
      if @qrparams
        @workers.find_each(batch_size: 20) do |work| 
            zip.write_deflated_file("#{work.firstname}-#{work.lastname}-#{work.id}-qrcode.png") do |sink|

                sink << work.generate_qr.to_s
            end
        end
      end

        if params[:certs]
              @workers.find_each(batch_size: 20) do |work| 
                   ...
                   PDF CODE
                   ...

                                  pdf.stylesheets << css

                                    # zos.print pdf.to_pdf
                                    sink << pdf.to_pdf.to_s
                               end ## Sink

                        end  ## Rec Loop

                work.certificates.each do |cert|
                  if cert.image && cert.image.file
                    ext = cert.image.file.extension.downcase
                      zip.write_deflated_file("#{work.firstname}-#{work.lastname}-#{cert.paperwork.title}-#{cert.id}.#{ext}") do |sink|

                          sink << cert.image.file.read
                    end ## Sink
                  else
                    logger.info cert.image
                  end
                end

          end ## Work Loop
    end

     end ## Zip Loop
 end
```

I can't figure out what is preventing the zip streaming. Any ideas?

#### Edit Aug 3

I set up a simplified action on my controller to test this. Similar to the code above but just only for CSVs with a set query.

Prior to the test action, I didn't see any errors in the production or development rails logs. I don't see any errors now either. There is a difference in the results of the curl test though.

Here is the result of using curl on my development server:

```
$ curl -v 127.0.0.1:3000/workers/data_export_test
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /workers/data_export_test HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/zip
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< X-Request-Id: 4299ee33-45ce-4343-a5fa-8465266aae30
< X-Runtime: 0.228082
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
PK�*��M
        report1.csvUT�[d���][s�:r~?���/I���q#�G�����>�]�3=�4,Q��3c������ݜ!  �D��Ö��?���~�����"j͡�����ᶨ�ѻ���c�Xį��Tͯ��������������h�w�n��6���_�Ϗ�����%��    3WIz�������b��z��e�};l��v��
                ��report1.csvUT�[d��PK���B���
Written using ZipTricks 4.6.0
```

The zip file comes out as expected.

Results are a little different on the production side:

```
$ curl -v http://[my server]/workers/data_export_test
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* Connected to [my server]/ (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 80 (#0)
> GET /workers/data_export_test HTTP/1.1
> Host: [my server]
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
< Content-Type: application/zip
< Date: Fri, 03 Aug 2018 16:38:45 GMT
< ETag: W/"179b594c438a742e70ceda4a7e54455b"
< Server: nginx/1.12.1
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Request-Id: e5ad7f84-34ea-4f90-8089-bde81799ed69
< X-Runtime: 0.112295
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Content-Length: 50
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host [my server] left intact
PK�ք�M
        report1.csvUT�[d��
```

The zip file does the same as before. Corrupt file of 50 bytes.

I don't see errors in any of my logs, nginx, puma, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working now. It was due to the nginx config.
I added some changes to my nginx config file and now it's good to go.

I changed my location section from this:

```
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://my_app; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
```

to this:

```
 location / {
          proxy_pass http://my_app; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Connection '';
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          chunked_transfer_encoding off;
          proxy_buffering off;
          proxy_cache off;
        }
```

It works as expected now.